# nuxt start requires node_modules to be present in order to run

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, node-modules, nuxt.js

I have a `nuxt-community/starter-template` project with minimal additions. My `package.json` looks like this

```
{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "docker-image": "nuxt build && docker build -t unijobs-www-temp .",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "NODE_ENV=production nuxt generate",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "precommit": "npm run lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands": "^5.0.13",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular": "^5.0.13",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid": "^5.0.13",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "0.0.22",
    "nuxt": "^1.0.0",
    "nuxt-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Local development looks fine, local `build` and `start` seem to work fine. However, it all goes south when I build the Docker image.
**PLEASE NOTE** this is not an issue with Docker, the same is true if I run equivalent steps on my own machine, in a new directory.

```
FROM node:stretch

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 3000

RUN npm -g i nuxt
RUN mkdir -p /app
ADD .nuxt /app/.nuxt
ADD static /app/static
WORKDIR /app

CMD ["nuxt", "start"]
```

This is what I find in the logs:

```
2018-06-05T12:27:19.910Z nuxt:render Rendering url /
{ Error: Cannot find module 'core-js/library/fn/promise' from '/app'
    at Function.module.exports [as sync] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nuxt/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:42:15)
    at r (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nuxt/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:8332:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (server-bundle.js:1429:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (server-bundle.js:27:30)
    at Object.module.exports.module.exports (server-bundle.js:105:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (server-bundle.js:27:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (server-bundle.js:1218:138)
    at __webpack_require__ (server-bundle.js:27:30)
    at server-bundle.js:92:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (server-bundle.js:95:10)
    at evaluateModule (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nuxt/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:8338:21)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nuxt/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:8396:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nuxt/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:8388:14
    at Object.renderToString (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nuxt/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:8564:9)
    at Renderer.renderRoute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nuxt/lib/core/renderer.js:344:41)
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  statusCode: 500,
  name: 'NuxtServerError' }
```

However, it all goes away as soon as I plug `node_modules` in, next to the `.nuxt` and `static` directories. It seems some of the modules are not bundled. My `nuxt.config.js` file is like

```
module.exports = {
  head: {
    // Skipping noise...
  },
  modules: [
    [ 'nuxt-fontawesome', {
      component: 'fa',
      imports: [
        { set: '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands' },
      ]
    }],
  ],
  loading: { color: '#3B8070' },
  build: {
    extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      if (isDev && isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })

// *** NOTE: In practice, I'm only using FA brands here, not the others ***

        config.resolve.alias['@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands$'] = '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands/shakable.es.js'  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: isnt that supposed to work as an "express" server?

Comment: Can you check the node version (`node -v`) from your docker image `node:stretch`. Nuxt needs node >= 8.4

Comment: That was fine, it has >= 8.4. The actual problem was me not understanding how deployment with npm works. The Dockerfile I pasted above is somewhat wrong: instead of installing nuxt global I should have done a `npm install` to install the runtime modules, and copied the `.nuxt` directory after building it from outside the container. In short: I was building inside the container and I didn't need to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found Nuxt build will not bundle files in node_modules, so if you want to bundle all dependencies into `.nuxt`, you should use **`nuxt build --standalone`**.

see here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/4292

hope this will help you :)

Comment: That is an interesting option…

Comment: could this be the accepted answer? Hopefully this feature will be documented soon https://github.com/nuxt/nuxtjs.org/issues/499